# How to create avd using device definition?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to create android virtual device for Google Nexus *from the console*. Now I'm using command

```
android -s create avd -n %avd_name% -t 1 -p %work_dir%\devices\%avd_name% -f -s 480x800
```

The result is not the same as if I've craeted it in the sdk manager. 
I wonder, how I could create avd based on device defenition "Galaxy Nexus" from the *console*.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the avdmanager to list all the device definitions available on your system

```
$ avdmanager list devices
```

Then you can use the device index or id to create the avd.

For example, the following command creates a new avd named "nexus9" using the x86 system image for API level 25 based on the google nexus 9 definition

```
avdmanager create avd -n google9 -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -d "Nexus 9"
```

- **-n** avd name
- **-k** sdk id
- **-d** device definition

Answer (score 0):

use the below command

```
   android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID> --skin  720 x 1,280 

   adb emu window scale 0.19
```

This may be help... Try this

Comment: emulator has tablet screen

Comment: I want to create emulator for "Google Nexus" phone.

Comment: same tablet screen (in portrait mode).

Comment: change 720 x 1280 to Galaxy Nexus resolution.. u ll get it

Comment: Google Nexus resolution is 720*1280, screen size 4.65in

Comment: Now it is a scaled tablet screen. Have you tried your advices ever?